# Can I spot the drones watching me in the sky with naked eyes?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, visibility

To quote [John Oliver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GObJtQOUJ4):

```
"Yemen, home to 26 million Yemeni people, and 27 million American drones."
```

While these numbers may be slightly exaggerated I started to wonder. As far as I know, military drones are used primarily for survaillance, meaning that they circle a potential target for hours on end to gather intelligence.

I immediately thought, that they would be spotted quickly, and any illegal activity would cease. Since they seem to be effective though, this can't really be true.

So my question is: Given typical operational parameters during survaillance, can military drones, like the Predator, be spotted with the naked eye if they are circling above you?

---

I tried to find an answer with some quick calculations of my own.

I can see quite a lot of airliners flying above me, and I can see their bodies quite easily. Airliners are larger though.

Some sizes I could gather are:

**A320** [Source](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus-A320-Familie)

```
Length: 37.57m
Wingspan: 34.1m
Body width: 3.96m
```

**Predator Drone** [Source](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_Grumman_RQ-4)

```
Length: 8.23m
Wingspan: 14.84m
Body width: 0.83m (estimated from picture)
```

When I look at just the length of the aircraft, I can calculate the angular size of the object in the sky if I know the altitude. I assume the A320 flies at around 32000 feet, or 9753m. For the drone I have no idea. But it can fly at 7620m and I would assume it stays a bit below, so I assume 6000m.

[image]

The angle of the object is then:

```
Angle = ArcTan(Length/Altitude)
```

The human eye has a resolution of [0.5-1 arc minutes](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufl%C3%B6sungsverm%C3%B6gen), or 0.0125°.

For the given aircraft I come to these values:

```
A320:
Angle = Atan(37.57/9753) = 0.22°

Predator:
Angle = Atan(8.23/6000) = 0.08°
```

So from the length, both aircraft should be visible. However, that doesn't seem to make sense, because they need to be wide enough as well. So for the body width's I get:

```
A320:
Angle = Atan(3.96/9753) = 0.024°

Predator:
Angle = Atan(0.83/6000) = 0.008°
```

So the A320 should be visible quite comfortably, while the drone should be invisible to the naked eye.

---

**But**

This is all theoretical. I don't know the operation of the predator, especially how high it flies. I also don't know what really determines visibility. Does the wingspan alter the numbers?

Can anyone share any actual insight?

Comment: I think those drone figures are not even an exaggeration. Exaggerations are based in fact; John Oliver has no idea how many American drones are in Yemen. By comparison, I understand that fewer than 1 million people have registered their hobby drones in the US so far.

Comment: This seems to be a problem of optics, not aviation. That said the resolution is dependent on the the diameter of the lens. The larger the lens, the better the resolution, but there are limits. See this question on Space.SE: [Were the Apollo lunar activities observed from Earth?](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9460/were-the-apollo-lunar-activities-observed-from-earth/9481#9481)

Comment: Thank you for your input @mins. The resolution of the eye is quite clear, given at 0.5-1 arc minute. I thought about Physics SE, but given that the question contains some parts about operating conditions of drones that I am unsure of and shape of aircraft (wings/body, instead of spherical approximation), I found it to be a better fit on Aviation. It's a corner case between the two in my opinion.

Comment: You may focus on the drone aspect here, and post the resolution question on Physics.SE. You may edit your question, which is about to be closed.

Comment: The airliner you see because the condensation trail is pointing at it. The drone flying at 3 or 5 km is inaudible and has no trail. If you knew where it is you might even see it, but without that knowledge you will be blind. The answer is no.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't see them but according to journalist [Jere Van Dyk](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/drone-warfare-jere-van-dyk-describes-what-it-is-like-to-find-yourself-underneath-a-uav/) you can hear a Predator drone overhead.

Comment: Thank you for the article, this was very interesting @TomMcW. But that's why I was asking, as the article, written from first-hand experience, for example disagrees with Peter's comment above you. Anyways, probably not a perfect match here then. :)

Comment: I suspect that linear angles as you've calculated isn't really what matters most; solid angle probably matters more. Square meters seen as square (milli) radians, for lack of more precisse verbiage.  After all a 1000m of kite string is harder to see than the 2m height of the person flying the kite, or even the 1m height of the kite, the difference being area. I suspect the Predator, with an order of magnitude less visible surface area than the A320, similarly benefits.

Comment: I can't read the German link about the resolution of the eye, but the typical meaning of the resolution of an optical sensor comes from the ability to distinguish two nearby points.  Against a clear blue sky, you would be able to detect the presence of an object smaller than that because it makes the total light falling on the retina lower.  However, you would be unable to tell if it was one drone or two.